# Customizing menu html

Tags: routes, theming

How do you set an id for the menu's root `<ul>` tag?

I know about the module "Menu Attributes" but that doesn't let me add an ID to the root `<ul>`, or at least I do not know how.

Also, I've seen a solution which uses `theme_menu_tree()` and a regex check, but that's just too hacky for my taste.

Answer (score 3):

In D7 default theme **bartik**, you can see the main menu is rendered using a theme hook `links__system_main_menu`:

```
 <div id="main-menu" class="navigation">
    <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
      'links' => $main_menu,
      'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'main-menu-links',
        'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
      ),
      'heading' => array(
        'text' => t('Main menu'),
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
      ),
    )); ?>
  </div> <!-- /#main-menu -->
```

`links__system_main_menu` is a theme hook pattern of the form [base hook]__[context]. 
When links are themed with `theme('links__system_main_menu', $vars)`, `theme()` will search for and use `theme_links__system_main_menu()` if it has been defined. If not, it will use `theme_links()`.

Drupal will use MYTHEME_links__system_main_menu(), if you define it in your theme.
Thus, you could implement the `hook_links__system_main_menu` as follows. Probably you will do that in the template.php file in your theme folder.:

```
function mytheme_links__system_main_menu($variables) {
  $html = "<div>\n";
  $html .= "  <ul id=\"your_id\">\n";  
  foreach ($variables['links'] as $key => $link) {
    $html .= "<li>".l($link['title'], $link['path'], $link)."</li>";
  }
  $html .= "  </ul>\n";
  $html .= "</div>\n";

  return $html;
}
```

This will override the `links__system_main_menu` theme and customize HTML output for the main menu.

**[Edit]**

If you are looking for the quickest way, you just need to tweak your page.tpl.php by adding an extra wrapper to the menu **ul**.
For example, in the Bartik theme,

```
  <div id="main-menu" class="navigation">
    <div id="your-id">
    <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
      'links' => $main_menu,
      'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'main-menu-links',
        'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
      ),
      'heading' => array(
        'text' => t('Main menu'),
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
      ),
    )); ?>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- /#main-menu -->
```

Then, you can access it using `#your-id ul{ }` in CSS or `$('#your-id ul')` in JS.
But, the above code is just for example, you should not hack the core themes or modules.
I assume you have your own theme.

Comment: So I basically have to recreate the whole menu structure just so that I can put a html attribute in an already existing menu? I am not sure about this. Why is this better than just search/replace?

Comment: So, you used the hook `mytheme_links__system_main_menu` as my answer?

Comment: yes, I did try out this solution, and it does work, but it kinda freaks me out. I have to edit two files, add a lot of arbitrary code which does not have any correlation with the original issue, which is, adding a simple html id attribute to a specific ul tag.

Comment: I just updated my answer. Please see the Edit section. It would be a simplest solution.

Comment: Your update is ok, but it's not what I need. The menu already has wrappers with ids. I need to set an id attribute for the `<ul>` tag. Not for a parent of it, and I woul preferably not write a whole menu structure just for this small thing.

Comment: Another issue with this approach is that it won't display submenus.

Comment: Another way is to write js code to add the html id to a specific <ul> tag. It would also require to create a javascript function. I think that's all Drupal can do for you. If you can find a very very simple solution by yourself, please post it and it will be appreciated.

Comment: And can you please tell me the purpose to set an id attribute for the <ul> tag?

Comment: Dear @Sithu, the question is not why, or for what purpose I want to do something, because if we are asking such questions, we could simply start at why should I use drupal, php or even the internet. The answer is of course, that I am trying to create the html document as I like it. Clean and simple. Also, using javascript to modify an already created html node might be a good solution for some people, but I don't think of that as a Drupal solution, just another hack.

Comment: @Ashnur: if you want to create the html document as you like, I think you should not use Drupal. If you use Drupal, you have to follow Drupal's rules, standards and API, but you can feel the power of Drupal. Theming in Drupal is not as simple as creating a custom html file.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up. I've had to come to this conclusion after having issues with such small things. Anyway, thanks for the help, your answers helped me understand more about drupal theming.

Answer (score 1):

You want to overwrite menu tree theming function as I mentioned in IRC. Easiest way would be to copy the attribute usage from theme_links.

Using this method does affect all menus, but it doesn't change anything for those which doesn't use attributes.

```
// Default theme_menu_tree
function theme_menu_tree($variables) {
  return '<ul class="menu">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}

// Overwritten theme_menu_tree
function YOURTHEME_menu_tree($variables) {
  $attributes = array("class" => array("menu"));
  if(isset($variables['attributes']))
    $attributes = array_merge_recursive($attributes, $variables['attributes']);
  return '<ul' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: That will affect every call to `theme_menu_tree()` though. As the OP wants to add a css _ID_ (most likely a specific one), this isn't really an option as it will result in multiple elements with the same ID. You wouldn't even get away with using `drupal_html_id()` as I imagine the whole point of this is so that the OP can set a predictable ID to target with CSS

Comment: I found a working hack with this approach where we use a string lookup to be sure we are modifying the one node we want to modyfy. 
I guess if this function could get a bit more info about what it's contents are going to be, it wouldn't be so hacky, but I am unsure if that's possible to achieve just with hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it right with the following code, based on @Sithu's response

```
function themename_links__system_main_menu($variables) {  
    $html = '<ul id="menu">'."\n";  
    foreach ($variables['links']['system_main-menu'] as $key => $link) {  
        if(is_array($link)){  
            $html .= "<li>".l($link['#title'], $link['#href'], $link)."</li>";  
        }                                                                                                                       
    }  
    $html .= "  </ul>\n";  
    return $html;  
}
```

Comment: but I still don't think that this should be the accepted answer. It's just way to much code for such a simple thing.

Comment: Why did you post the same answer as a different post? This is not a way of this community.

Comment: If you read it carefully you will see that it's not quite the same answer. The one you posted thrown a lot of errors, this one worked for me.

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but the logic and hook usage are the same. I did not expect from you to accept my answer. And you should not also expect error-free ready-made codes from this community. You can also see some accepted answers in this site are just advice.